# CSS Flexbox Margin Top to Align Items

Tags: css

I'm trying to align the price and the view button in two divs but can't seem to get it right.

I've set display flex on the divs and margin-top : auto on the element but it's not working and since I am using Astra theme, I can't modify the HTML code.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 315px;
}
.button {
  display: block;
}
.astra-shop-summary-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.price {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex">
  <li class="">
    <div class="astra-shop-thumbnail-wrap">
      <a href="#" class="">
        <img width="300" height="300" src="" class="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="astra-shop-summary-wrap">
      <span class="">Lorem ipsum</span>
      <a href="#">
        <h2 class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h2>
      </a>
      <span class="price">47.50</span>
      <a href="" class="button">View</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <div class="astra-shop-thumbnail-wrap">
      <a href="#" class="">
        <img width="300" height="300" src="" class="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="astra-shop-summary-wrap">
      <span class="">Lorem ipsum</span>
      <a href="#">
        <h2 class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </h2>
      </a>
      <span class="price">47.50</span>
      <a href="" class="button">View</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to align the price and view button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly how you want things to be aligned then here's a solution without touching the template. (Check snipped result in full page).

Only change:

`li div:last-child { flex-grow: 1; }`

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 315px;
}

li .astra-shop-summary-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li div:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

li .button {
  display: block;
}

li .price {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex">
  <li class="">
    <div class="astra-shop-thumbnail-wrap">
      <a href="#" class="">
        <img width="300" height="300" src="" class="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="astra-shop-summary-wrap">
      <span class="">Lorem ipsum</span>
      <a href="#">
        <h2 class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h2>
      </a>
      <span class="price">47.50</span>
      <a href="" class="button">View</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <div class="astra-shop-thumbnail-wrap">
      <a href="#" class="">
        <img width="300" height="300" src="" class="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="astra-shop-summary-wrap">
      <span class="">Lorem ipsum</span>
      <a href="#">
        <h2 class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </h2>
      </a>
      <span class="price">47.50</span>
      <a href="" class="button">View</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way with the least modification to your code is to just add a dummy h2 placeholder tag. The second way is a more robust solution

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 315px;
}
.button {
  display: block;
}
.astra-shop-summary-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.price {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex">
  <li class="">
    <div class="astra-shop-thumbnail-wrap">
      <a href="#" class="">
        <img width="300" height="300" src="" class="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="astra-shop-summary-wrap">
      <span class="">Lorem ipsum</span>
      <a href="#">
        <h2 class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h2>
      </a>
      <span class="price">47.50</span>
      <a href="" class="button">View</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <div class="astra-shop-thumbnail-wrap">
      <a href="#" class="">
        <img width="300" height="300" src="" class="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="astra-shop-summary-wrap">
      <span class="">Lorem ipsum</span>
      <a href="#">
        <h2 class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2></a>
        <h2 style="margin:0">&nbsp;</h2>
      <span class="price">47.50</span>
      <a href="" class="button">View</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 315px;
}
.button {
  display: block;
}
.astra-shop-summary-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.price {
  margin-top: auto;
}

#x{
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;}

.y{
width:315px;
margin-left:40px;}
```

```html
<ul class="flex">
  <li class="">
    <div class="astra-shop-thumbnail-wrap">
      <a href="#" class="">
        <img width="300" height="300" src="" class="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="astra-shop-summary-wrap">
      <span class="">Lorem ipsum</span>
      <a href="#">
        <h2 class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h2>
      </a>
     
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <div class="astra-shop-thumbnail-wrap">
      <a href="#" class="">
        <img width="300" height="300" src="" class="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="astra-shop-summary-wrap">
      <span class="">Lorem ipsum</span>
      <a href="#">
        <h2 class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2></a>       
     
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id = 'x'>
   <div class = 'y'>
      <span class="price">47.50</span>
      <a href="" class="button">View</a>
   </div>
   <div class = 'z'>
      <span class="price">47.50</span>
      <a href="" class="button">View</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

EDITED:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 315px;
}
.button {
  display: initial;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 20px;
}
.astra-shop-summary-wrap {
  display: initial;
  position: relative;
  padding-top:10px
}
.price {
  margin-top: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 2px;
}
```

Comment: that's not how to comment css.  Use /*    */ .  The rest of your answer doesn't answer the question

Comment: u can comment that way too...Also, do you want to align those items to top of other information except image?

Comment: no, you can not comment that way correctly.  // basically is gibberish in css.  It works only because css doesn't know what you mean.  The CORRECT way is to use /*  */.  Again, if i could down vote your answer again I would as it doesn't provide any useful information and doesn't answer the question.  Run the snippet to see what your code does

Comment: I edited my answer and written only css. Try that out. There are many correct way and i have only used it to refer that you need a comment. Also, Do you even know that using /* */ takes how much time to compile?

Comment: have you tried it yet or still finding difficult to implement?

Comment: Also, Your question heading means that you want to align items which is already correct in your answer and your question description means that you want to align price and view to top(Above image or above all text content)?
Please be specific while seeking answers on CSS3. You need to be very precise while asking